# How to break line in a text node in a tikz forest diagram

Tags: diagrams, tikz-trees, forest, flow-charts

I need to break line in a node text in a tikz forest diagram. I tried to add \ or \newline in the node text, but that did not work.

Here is the sample code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \begin{forest}
        forked edges, folder indent=1cm,
        where={level()<1}{}{folder, grow'=east},
        where={level()>0}{l sep+=1cm}{},
        for tree={
            fork sep=4mm,
            thick, edge=thick,
            font=\sffamily,
            if n children=0{if n=1{yshift=-5mm}{}, for parent={s sep=0mm}}{draw, minimum height=4ex, minimum width=4cm}
        }
        [Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet con, calign=edge midpoint, s sep=2cm, font=\bfseries\sffamily
            [Lorem ips
                [Lorem ipsum
                    [Lorem ipsum dolor sit.]
                    [Lorem ipsum dolor s]
                ]
                [Lorem ipsum dolor si
                    [Lorem ipsum dolor s]
                    [Lorem ipsum dolo]
                ]
            ]
            [Lorem ipsum dolor sit am
                [Lorem ipsum d]
                [Lorem ipsum]
                [Lorem ipsum]
            ]
        ]
    \end{forest}
    \caption{A small tree}
    \label{fig:smart_card_types}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding `align=center` everywhere will work but give strange-looking results if line breaks are added to the root or leaf nodes. For the root, we need to adjust `anchor` to avoid 'squashing' the path to the children. For the leaves, we need to change `child anchor` and fudge something, depending on what we want here. It's also probably best to use `align=left` for these nodes.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
    forked edges, 
    folder indent=1cm,
    anchor=children,
    for descendants={l sep'+=1cm,folder,grow'=east},
    for tree={
      fork sep'=4mm,
      thick, edge=thick,
      font=\sffamily,
      if n children=0{
        if n=1{yshift=-5mm}{},
        for parent={s sep'=0mm},
        align=left,
        edge path'={%
          (!u.parent anchor) -- ++(\forestoption{fork sep},0pt) |- ([yshift=-.75\baselineskip].child anchor)
        },
        child anchor=north west,
      }{
        draw, 
        minimum height=4ex, 
        minimum width=4cm,
        align=center,
      }
    },
    [Lorem ipsum dolor\\sit amet con, calign=edge midpoint, s sep'=2cm, font=\bfseries\sffamily
        [Lorem ips
            [Lorem ipsum
                [Lorem ipsum\\dolor sit.]
                [Lorem ipsum dolor s]
            ]
            [Lorem ipsum\\dolor si
                [Lorem\\ipsum\\dolor\\s]
                [Lorem ipsum dolo]
            ]
        ]
        [Lorem ipsum\\dolor sit am
            [Lorem ipsum d]
            [Lorem ipsum]
            [Lorem ipsum]
        ]
    ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Somewhat silly-looking results due to overly zealous line breaking:

[image: resulting tree]

I also removed some unnecessary code from the OP's original.

Answer (score 0):

Add alignment (`align`) key, and then you can use `\\` to separate your text in different lines.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[!ht]
        \centering
        \begin{forest}
            forked edges, folder indent=1cm,
            where={level()<1}{}{folder, grow'=east},
            where={level()>0}{l sep+=1cm}{},
            for tree={
                align=center, %% ADDED
                fork sep=4mm,
                thick, edge=thick,
                font=\sffamily,
                if n children=0{if n=1{yshift=-5mm}{}, for parent={s sep=0mm}}{draw, minimum height=4ex, minimum width=4cm}
            }
            [Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet con, calign=edge midpoint, s sep=2cm, font=\bfseries\sffamily
            [Lorem ips
            [Lorem ipsum
            [Lorem ipsum dolor sit.]
            [Lorem ipsum dolor s]
            ]
            [Lorem ipsum dolor si
            [Lorem ipsum dolor s]
            [Lorem ipsum dolo]
            ]
            ]
            [Lorem ipsum\\dolor sit am
            [Lorem ipsum d]
            [Lorem\\ipsum]
            [Lorem ipsum]
            ]
            ]
        \end{forest}
        \caption{A small tree}
        \label{fig:smart_card_types}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: output]

Comment: Try inserting the line break in the root node ....